# Is there a way to make "text-align: center;" place the lines in ascending size?

Tags: html, css

By default, `text-align: center;` places the lines of content in descending size, like so:

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  width: 20rem;
}
```

```html
<p>Get your team in sync, no matter your location. Streamline processes, create team rituals, and watch productivity soar.</p>
```

Is there a way to make it so that the lines of content are displayed in ascending size instead? Here's what I mean:

[image: hello world]

I've tried playing around with flexbox, widths, different text properties and whatnot but I just can't find a solution.

Comment: It's aligning the words according to available width and space. Instead of `rem` try using `px` for width and just check how does it work. To make it look like desired output, you will need to add those lines in some wrapper element like `<span>`.

Comment: not sure it's possible without js or split the text into more paragraphs, you can play with this [https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playdemo.asp?filename=playcss_accent-color](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playdemo.asp?filename=playcss_accent-color)

Comment: This is incorrect. There is no attempt by the system to place lines in ascending order of length. Just add a small word at the start and you will see the first line can be longer. It sounds as though fitting text to a pyramid shape might be the closest you can get to what you want. Would that do?

Comment: Basically, NO there isn't.